# Printing to a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I need to print headers and data rows to a CSV file. Here is my code:

```
import csv

import sys

  with open(r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\raw_inpuy.csv','rb') as csvfile:

        reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        first=True
        data={}
        for row in reader:
            if first:
                 first= False
                   continue
            if not int(row[1]) in data:
                 data[int(row[1])]=[]
               data[int(row[1])].append(float(row[3]))


    with open (r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\outcome.csv','wb') as f_out:
        outwriter=csv.writer(f_out,delimiter=',')
       f_out.write(";".join(['Size','S1','S2','S3','S4']))
       for item in data:
        row=[item]
        row.extend(data[item])
        f_out.write(";".join(map(str,row)))
```

I get this error:

```
**ERROR Expected a character buffer obj**
```

Comment: You need to use `csv.writer` to create a [*writer object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: No! you can't just rewrite the question completely based on first answers. rollback, accept an answer and ask another question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should feed `writer.write` with an `str` not a `list`:

```
 writer.write(";".join(['Size','S1','S2','S3','S4']))
```

also:

```
 writer.write(";".join(map(str, row)))
```

Comment: New error for the last line is: 'sequence item 0: expected string, int found' what I am writing to the csv consists of strings and integers

Comment: try: `writer.write(";".join(map(str, row)))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to build your own CSV records, let the `csv` module handle it. Like this:

```
import csv

data = [[10, 'foo', 'bar', 'blue', 'green'],
        [20, 'bar', 'foo', 'blue', 'green'],
        [30, 'ba', 'bar', 'red', 'white']]

with open (r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\outcome.csv','w') as file:
  writer = csv.writer(file)
  writer.writerow(['Size','S1','S2','S3','S4'])
  for row in data:
    writer.writerow(row)
```